# Document management system

Tags: xetex, programming, latex-misc

Is there any free / open source DMS for latex documents , which is simple to install and manage, not bulky (enterprize grade), help search the document and has revision control if possible?

---

(I've tried to second-guess this a bit. Please feel at ease to adapt, roll back, etc.)

---

Such a system should include, if possible:

- Versioning, and provision for shared development of, (La)TeX source, including both texts and packages
- Versioned storage of non-source material (E.g. images)
- Facilities for document formatting and review
- Facilities for document release (I.e. special distinguished versions)
- Storage of "frozen", released output documents (e.g. PDF, DVI, ...)
- Full text search (input and/or output)

Comment: As it stands I don't thing this is going to get insightful answers. Could you elaborate on what you expect from a 'document management system'? Version control, _etc._ is happily covered by standard programmers tools such as Subversion, Git or Mercurial, all of which are open source and for which GUIs are available. Those really are not LaTeX-specific things in any case.

Comment: does `git` fit your needs?

Answer (score 1):

I believe a colleague uses subversion for his LaTeX documents - which isn't aimed at LaTeX but programming itself.

I think a part of the question is really "what do you want it to do"? If you only want to manage the LaTeX source files, you should be fine with any version control system aimed at source files.
If you want to manage the finished documents you may need more.

(Having said that, I have no personal experience with version control.)

Update in response to updated query:
I believe most features would be covered in regular version control, except the ability to handle compiled pdf documents.

Comment: Possibly more of a comment than an answer? (I agree that what is needed is more clarity in the question.)